# How to run Microsoft Learn example 'Build your GCC C/C++ app'?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to follow this simple Microsoft Learn example for Azure DevOps:

[Build your GCC C/C++ app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/c-cpp/gcc?view=azure-devops&tabs=vsts#get-sample-app-code)

but I can't follow it.

For Azure Repos, step 1 states:

```
On the Code page for your project, select the option to Import repository.
```

Where is the 'Code' page and where is the Import option? (Note I already have a repo in my project).

Later, in section 'Set up continuous integration' step 1 says:

```
Under the Build and Release menu, select Builds then New to create a new build definition.
```

Where is the 'Build and Release' menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where is the 'Code' page and where is the Import option? (Note I already have a repo in my project).

You can navigate to **Repos -> Import Repository** and input the Github repo URL.

For example:

[image]

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Import a Git repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops)

> Where is the 'Build and Release' menu?

You can navigate the Pipelines tab and then you will see the **Pipelines tab** and **Releases tab**.

[image]

The **Pipelines** tab is the Build menu. You can create the Build definition in the Pipelines tab.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Create your first pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Ctfs-2018-2%2Cbrowser)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand better now. Sorry, I thought I had already commented.   I think it was hard to work it out from the Microsoft article.  Is StackOverflow the best place to get help with Azure DevOps?

Comment: @DavidA If your requirements are related to troubleshooting or how to do it in Azure DevOps. StackOverflow is a good place to get help. If your requirements are related to the issue in Azure DevOps itself, you can also report the issue to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/report